# Azure Powershell issue

Tags: powershell, azure

I am facing a unique issue while running powershell script on one of our environments. The error is as below

> Import-AzureRmContext : Access to the path 'Windows Azure Powershell' is denied.
>
> At PowerShellScripts\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1:22 char:1

I am simply using the command

`Import-AzureRmContext -Path $path`

When I run this command on PowerShell Console I get the output. Same thing is not working while invoking it through code on Server 2012 R2.

Comment: What is the $path value. Did you try running that script as administrator ? Try to set your path in a common area or on the desktop of the exexuting user to see if it changes something.

Comment: $path is the file path from where AzureRmcontext will be read. It is Azureprofile.json file

Comment: Running as Admin would work. If not, might help looking at the actual NTFS permissions on the target file.

You could also use the -Force parameter on the Import Cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please ensure you could access `$path` in your Power Shell console, you could test `Run as Administrator`. For test, you could change your path to other directory, such as `c:\test.json`.

If it work, you could check your Azure Power Shell version, use the following cmdlet.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

Currently, the latest version is 4.3.1. You could download and install it from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

I suggest you could re-create json file. Firstly, login your Azure.

```
##re-create json file
Save-AzureRmContext -Path d:\test.json

$path="d:\test.json"
Import-AzureRmContext -Path $path
```